# Error in Connecting to SQL Server from a web form

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to connect SQL Server in my webform program.

I use this command :

```
Connection = new SqlConnection("server=sharmi-PC/MSSQL2012;database=PeopleDb;trusted_connection=true");
```

but I get an error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in PeopleManagement.BusinessLogic.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My server name in SQL Server is

```
sharmi-PC\MSSQL2012
```

Comment: Please check that your MS SQL service and running.

Comment: try with `sharmi-PC` only and i hope you are giving userid and password in your code

Comment: Change the connection string to BackSlash (`\\`) not forward Slash (`/`). `sharmi-PC\MSSQL2012` means there is an instance called `MSSQL2012` (which isn't a default installation) on host `sharmi-PC`

Comment: @xtnd8 .... it is running and open

Comment: @StuartLC .... use ' / ' cause this error : Error 1 Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @tinka , I used it , but it has same error

Comment: In C# you need to escape it. "server=sharmi-PC\\MSSQL2012;dat...." or @"server=sharmi-PC\MSSQL2012;dat" i.e. either double slash, or prepend `@` to the whole connection string.

Comment: @StuartLC .... Yeah! Soleved.... I use '@' and '\' and now it run correctly... Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say yourself that your server name is

```
sharmi-PC\MSSQL2012
```

then why aren't you using that in your connection??

Use this:

```
Connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=sharmi-PC\MSSQL2012;database=PeopleDb;trusted_connection=true");
```

Use the **proper** notation for server/instance name - a **backslash** (as in `sharmi-PC\MSSQL2012`) - not a forward slash as you used (`sharmi-PC/MSSQL2012`) ....